# How to use VLOOKUP() + QUERY() + IMPORTRANGE() with mutiple conditions?

Tags: google-sheets, import, google-sheets-formula, formula, google-query-language

I currently have this one working fine with 01 condition, but I can't manage to include another criteria:

```
=Arrayformula(if(A3:A="","",IFNA(vlookup(E3:E,QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("1gh5w0czg2JuoA3i5wPu8_eOpC4Q4TXIRhmUrg53nKMU","Arrayformula VLOOKUP multiple columns!A1:C"), "select Col1, Col2, Col3 label Col3 'Qtd'",0),3,0))))
```

I've started by concatenating `A3:A&E3:E`, but I don't know how to get the data ranges for comparison in this fashion using `QUERY()`.

Here is the result VS expectation:
[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Also, here is an example for tests:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1gh5w0czg2JuoA3i5wPu8_eOpC4Q4TXIRhmUrg53nKMU/edit?usp=sharing

Appreciate any help - as usual!
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/o9FQT.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A3:A="",,IFNA(VLOOKUP(E3:E&" "&F3:F,
 QUERY({FLATTEN(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(
 IMPORTRANGE("1gh5w0czg2JuoA3i5wPu8_eOpC4Q4TXIRhmUrg53nKMU", "Arrayformula VLOOKUP multiple columns!A1:B")),,9^9)),
 IMPORTRANGE("1gh5w0czg2JuoA3i5wPu8_eOpC4Q4TXIRhmUrg53nKMU", "Arrayformula VLOOKUP multiple columns!C1:C")}, 
 "select Col1,Col2 label Col2 'x'", 0), 2, 0))))
```

[image]

Comment: what the h***, thunder speed, upped

Comment: That does solve the question - indeed. Bumped into a new situation, where there are columns in between. I'm throwing another question. Couldn't solve it by myself. Thank you!