# How can I use VLOOKUP + QUERY + IMPORTRANGE using multiple conditions in non-sequential columns in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, import, google-sheets-formula, formula, google-query-language

The formula/solution below, kindly provided by a sheets genius, solves it when the criteria/ranges obtained are next to each other, but just bumped into a situation where there are other columns in between. I thought that by selecting the wanted column in the first query would get me in the right direction, but it doesn't, so here I am:

Here is the formula sitting in cell `H3`:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A3:A="",,IFNA(VLOOKUP(F3:F&" "&G3:G,
 QUERY({FLATTEN(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(
 IMPORTRANGE("1gh5w0czg2JuoA3i5wPu8_eOpC4Q4TXIRhmUrg53nKMU", "Arrayformula VLOOKUP multiple columns!A1:C")),,9^9)),
 IMPORTRANGE("1gh5w0czg2JuoA3i5wPu8_eOpC4Q4TXIRhmUrg53nKMU", "Arrayformula VLOOKUP multiple columns!D1:D")}, 
 "select Col1,Col2 label Col2 'x'", 0), 2, 0))))
```

Here is the example [sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1gh5w0czg2JuoA3i5wPu8_eOpC4Q4TXIRhmUrg53nKMU/edit?usp=sharing)

[image]

Comment: hi, please link the previous [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73626158/19529694) in your question to benifit future visitors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A3:A="",,IFNA(VLOOKUP(F3:F&" "&G3:G,
 QUERY({
 IMPORTRANGE("1gh5w0czg2JuoA3i5wPu8_eOpC4Q4TXIRhmUrg53nKMU", "Arrayformula VLOOKUP multiple columns!A1:A")&" "&
 IMPORTRANGE("1gh5w0czg2JuoA3i5wPu8_eOpC4Q4TXIRhmUrg53nKMU", "Arrayformula VLOOKUP multiple columns!C1:C"),
 IMPORTRANGE("1gh5w0czg2JuoA3i5wPu8_eOpC4Q4TXIRhmUrg53nKMU", "Arrayformula VLOOKUP multiple columns!D1:D")}, 
 "select Col1,Col2"), 2, ))))
```

[image]

Comment: the header problem when aggregated with 9^9 in the first IMPORTRANGE ?

Comment: You can discard the `Query` header since it's a range of a `Vlookup` see [this image](https://i.imgur.com/RW0ll19.jpg)

Comment: @Osm yup, I made it shorter

Comment: Hi! I see that if it worked, it's solved and marked as such, but it gives me the error here: ```Unable to parse query string for Function QUERY parameter 2: NO_COLUMN: Col2```. Here's the formula: ```=Arrayformula(if(E10:E="";;IFNA(vlookup(A10:A&" "&E10:E;
QUERY({
IMPORTRANGE("FILE_ID";"Pedidos!L1:L")&" "&
IMPORTRANGE("FILE_ID";"Pedidos!B1:B");
IMPORTRANGE("FILE_ID";"Pedidos!D1:D")}; "select Col1,Col2");2;0))))```. Error simple to pin point? Thanks a million for all your help!

Comment: @onit yes. use: `=Arrayformula(if(E10:E="";;IFNA(vlookup(A10:A&" "&E10:E; QUERY({ IMPORTRANGE("FILE_ID";"Pedidos!L1:L")&" "& IMPORTRANGE("FILE_ID";"Pedidos!B1:B")\ IMPORTRANGE("FILE_ID";"Pedidos!D1:D")}; "select Col1,Col2");2;0))))`

Comment: Thanks - Last question: WHYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY?

Comment: @onit locale :) if you intend to use ; as separator than ; will put stuff under each other while \ will put stuff next to each other (notice the \ before the 3rd importrange)

Comment: @onit https://stackoverflow.com/q/73767719/5632629